# What game uses dice with shields, fleur-de-lis and rapier hilts?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

A while ago I bought some dice from the "discount dice jar" of mismatched dice at my [local games store](https://zacatrus.es/sevilla). The store personnel claim to have no idea where these dice came from.

From what I can gather, the symbols on the dice are shields, [fleur-de-lis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur-de-lis), and the [basket hilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basket-hilted_sword) of a rapier (or similar renaissance-era sword). The blue dice show two of each symbol, whereas the red dice show three shields and three swordhilts. Dice are 15mm in size.

[image: Photograph of strange dice]

So, which game uses this kind of dice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dice are from the game "Mousquetaires du Roy" ("The King's Musketeers")

[image]
[Board Game Geek Entry](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/78954/mousquetaires-du-roy)